# Identify Source Button of Modal Dialog

Tags: button, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

i got a simple scenario where i have an administrative list of DB-Entries. On click i call the remote-attribute and display the data.

Now the Modal Dialog contains Action-Buttons like "Delete", "Approve", "Nothing".

So whenever i click one of those buttons, i'd like to get the ID of the DB-Entry.

Going by [this PullRequest on GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6825) on Bootstrap 2.3 there was a `relatedTarget` attribute on the `event`. Apparently on v3 this has been removed. So i'm really wondering on how i should implement this kind of feature.

```
//Syntax Bootstrap v2.3
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e){
    console.log(e.relatedTarget);
});

//Syntax Bootstrap v3.0
????
```

A fiddle shouldn't really help to understand the question, but [here's one anyways](http://jsfiddle.net/Zn9JP/)

Answer (score 0):

Since i have identified buttons on the modal dialog, a functionality like this works. Though for some reason i feel for this to be a little messy and I'm still wondering if there's a different solution to this:

```
// Button to open the Modal Dialog
<a href="#someLink" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDiv" data-article-id="1">Foo</a>

// Button inside the Modal view
<a href="#" id="delete-article">delete</a>
```

And then the JS to get the article ID on Delete-Button-Click:

```
$('#delete-article').on('click', function(){
    var articleId = $('#modalDiv').data('bs.modal').options.articleId;
    // artticleId = 1
});
```

Since i have to make another "query" onto the DOM, i feel for this method to be quite dirty. If there's any other way to get the data in a more performant way, I'd gladly take that information :)